# API request from amplify app to Elasticbeanstalk API that uses subdomain fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-amplify

I successfully deployed my API to Elasticbeanstalk, it works and is accessible.

API is configured with https over domain `api.mydomain.com`

I also have Amplify app built in React which is using this API. the amplify app is configured with domain `mydomain.com`

The react app is using Elasticbeanstalk API and whenever it tries to execute request I get 400 CORS

For instance, on login route I even return CORS response headers and it does not work

What are the possible solutions here?
Should I add my Elasticbeanstalk API as backend environment for Amplify?

Thanks in advance